# What framework/tool to use for building web based mobile apps with support for push notifications to device?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mobile, meteor

I have recently been playing around with Meteor.js and it looks like a really awesome tool to build realtime client centric web apps in javascript. Can someone suggest some good frameworks/tools i can use for creating web based mobile apps, which would support stuff like push notifications to the device ?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you need a wrapper framework with this ability. Use any framework like jQuery mobile, Sencha touch ... and wrap it with Phonegap/Cordova framework.

Phonegap (depending on mobile platform) has a plugin to interact with push notifications.

And [this](https://github.com/shaders/phonegap-cordova-push-notifications) is a plugin.

Google Phonegap if you need more information. It is good to know, phonegap is frameworks old name, new name is Cordova. You can use it on any mobile platform.